# Stored Procedure: Variable passed from PHP alters second half of query string

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures, case

Basically, we have an ASP website right now that I'm converting to PHP. We're still using the MSSQL server for the DB -- it's not moving.

In the ASP, now, there's an include file with a giant sql query that's being executed. This include sits on a lot of pages and this is a simple version of what happens. Pages A, B and C all use this include file to return a listing.

In ASP, Page A passes through variable A to the include file - page B passes through variable B -- page C passes through variable C, and so on.

The include file builds the SQL query like this:

`sql = "SELECT * from table_one LEFT OUTER JOIN table_two ON table_one.id = table_two.id"`

then adds (remember, ASP), based on the variable passed through from the parent page,

```
Select Case sType
Case "A"
sql = sql & "WHERE LOWER(column_a) <> 'no' AND LTRIM(ISNULL(column_b),'') <> '' ORDER BY column_a
Case "B"
sql = sql & "WHERE LOWER(column_c) <> 'no' ORDER BY lastname, firstname
Case "C"
sql = sql & "WHERE LOWER(column_f) <> 'no' OR LOWER(column_g) <> 'no' ORDER BY column_g
```

As you notice, every string that's added on as the second part of the sql query is different than the previous; not just one variable can be substituted out, which is what has me stumped.

How do I translate this case / switch into the stored procedure, based on the varchar input that I pass to the stored procedure via PHP?

This stored procedure will actually handle a query listing for about 20 pages, so it's a hefty one and this is my first major complicated one. I'm getting there, though! I'm also just more used to MySQL, too. Not that they're that different. :P

Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Stephanie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I translate this case / switch into the stored procedure, based on the varchar input that I pass to the stored procedure via PHP?

In SQL Server, the [CASE expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) is **not** for control-of-flow like IF/ELSE.

Use:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(max)
    SET @SQL = N'SELECT ...'

    SET @SQL = @SQL + CASE sType
                        WHEN 'A' THEN ' WHERE ... '
                        WHEN 'B' THEN ' WHERE ... '
                        WHEN 'C' THEN ' WHERE ... '
                        ELSE ' '
                      END
BEGIN

  EXEC sp_executesql @SQL

END
```

Lest we forget the [ominous tale of Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/), best to read [The curse and blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html).

Comment: haha. That Dynamic SQL page is mighty long, but I'll read what I can. I definitely know the dangers of injection, so I appreciate it.

Also, you totally win for not only the printed out code, here, but an XKCD comic. 

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to do dynamic SQL in the stored proc. This link will help you out:
http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Comment: Ironically enough I had just found that page right before you posted this. Thank you so much!